# How to clean the face of a newborn?

Tags: infant, newborn, health

She is 14 day old. The cord clip has fallen off.
How to clean the face of a newborn without letting the ***soap*** go inside the eyes and mouth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When ours was that age we used only a very little soap lathered up across a very thin, slightly moist washcloth. We had another moist washcloth to rinse with.

Here are some things to remember:

- A baby's skull has not fully formed at this age. **Do not** press hard at all! This can cause all sorts of issues
- Wipe gently with a soft cloth that is not overly absorbed in water! Baby skin is soft and easily scratched and also, too much water will obviously lead to water and soap going into a facial orifice.
- Listen to baby. S/he will let you know if s/he is uncomfortable.
- At this age, be sure to control the head and neck and, if feasible, have someone help you.

Answer (score 9):

For a 10 day old, I'd not use soap at all. [From the Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/healthy-baby/PR00041):

> The American Academy of Pediatrics recommends sponge baths until the umbilical cord stump falls off — which might take up to three weeks... Wet the washcloth, wring out excess water and wipe your baby's face. **There's no need to use soap.**

Comment: sorry, she is 14 day old and cord clip has fallen off.

Comment: The National Institute of Health concurs - bathing instructions [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2528704/#!po=8.33333) - see page 2. Water only for baby's face.

Answer (score 0):

You can use soap or just water. Mustela also has this cleanser that you can use on their diaper area or face. It's a rinse free solution. I squirt some on a small cotton pad during bath and wipe it on dd's face. When I run out I'll just use water or soap but I had some of this left over so that's what I'm using now.